# Protractor is showing the same stack trace for different errors

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor to test and angularJS application.

Most of the errors I am getting are showing the same stack traces related to promises, when this is not where the actual error is occurring.

Is this a config / setup error?

For example, if I use an undefined function I get a stack trace that does not relate to the where the undefined function is used.

example stack trace:

> at /foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:102:16
>
> at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
>
> at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2464:25)
>
> at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:563:12) `

Protractor version: 2.0.0
Jasmine version: 2.1.1

Comment: Could you try upgrading jasmine to 2.2.1?

Comment: Ah yeah, that seem to have work. Cheers